# Building an iOS React Native app with GitHub Actions

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, continuous-integration, github-actions

It appears that the `macOS` machine type (`runs-on`) in GitHub Actions (CI/CD) sets `RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER=1`. I verified that behavior by creating a [bare repo with a simple GH workflow for macOS](https://github.com/williamhaley/test-gh-actions-macos-env) and verified the ENV var is set.

```
RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER=1
```

That variable is problematic. It has a significant impact on the Xcode build process. The default `Start packager` Build Phase in Xcode will not start the metro packager if `RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER` is set, which is the case here.

```
...
if [ -z "${RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER+xxx}" ] ; then
...
```

Because the packager never starts, the `Bundle React Native code and images` run script is doomed to failure. The build fails with this error and the JS bundle is never generated for the app archive because the packager is not running.

> ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
> PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images ...
> (1 failure)
> [23:43:23]: Exit status: 65

This is the specific part of that build phase that fails.

```
+ ../node_modules/expo-updates/scripts/create-manifest-ios.sh
Error: Failed to connect to the packager server. If you did not start this build by running 'react-native run-android', you can start the packager manually by running 'react-native start' in the project directory. (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8081)
    at /Users/will/dev/changes/node_modules/expo-updates/scripts/createManifest.js:40:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

A few questions come to mind:

- Why would GitHub set that var? I can't find any meaningful documentation on it. By default, it breaks the "normal" Xcode React Native build process.
- The ENV var seems intentionally set by GitHub, so what's the alternative they're pushing users towards in order to generate a React Native iOS build?
- Unsetting `RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER` seems like a viable options, but are there drawbacks to that approach? I'd *assume* it was initially set for a good reason.

I realize the `react-native bundle` command exists and allows for explicitly bundling JS assets, but it seems odd to have to do that when we already have a perfectly good `Bundle React Native code and images` build phase that's meant to accomplish exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

> Why would GitHub set that var?

I'm not sure, honestly. GitHub [describes *some* of their default env vars](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/using-environment-variables#default-environment-variables), with the significant omission of the `RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER` for my situation.

> The ENV var seems intentionally set by GitHub, so what's the alternative they're pushing users towards in order to generate a React Native iOS build?

They don't seem to give any guidance. They seemed to have made a call on setting this var and leave it to users to figure things out.

> Unsetting RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER seems like a viable options, but are there drawbacks to that approach? I'd assume it was initially set for a good reason.

There are some drawbacks. Or rather, simply unsetting this var isn't a "fix" that solves all problems. At least, not in my case.

---

My solution was to hack a couple of the build phase scripts and to leverage the `CI` env var that is set to `"true"` in GitHub.

**Start Packager**

I added this towards the top.

```
export RCT_METRO_PORT="${RCT_METRO_PORT:=8081}"
echo "export RCT_METRO_PORT=${RCT_METRO_PORT}" > "${SRCROOT}/../node_modules/react-native/scripts/.packager.env"

# My changes...
if [ "${CI}" = "true" ];
then
  sh -c "bash $SRCROOT/../node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command" &> /tmp/packager.log &
  exit 0
fi

... rest of the script.
```

**Bundle React Native code and images**

I modified the script like so to clean up my launch of the packager above. In hindsight, I don't know if this is necessary.

```
export NODE_BINARY=$(which node)
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
../node_modules/expo-updates/scripts/create-manifest-ios.sh
if [ "${CI}" = "true" ];
then
    kill -9 `ps ax | grep -i 'launchPackager.command' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'` || true
    kill -9 `ps ax | grep -i 'cli.js start' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'` || true
fi
```

Finally, something that I did not expect, was after getting the packager working I found another issue. The `[CP-User] [RNFB] Core Configuration` hung forever.

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3706) and [addressed in their docs](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/pull/3989). The fix for me was to simply add an empty `firebase.json` file

```
{
  "react-native": {
  }
}
```

With all that, the builds proceed as expected. Some of these may just be general "have fun troubleshooting in a CI environment!" types of issues, but the `RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER` was subtle and particularly annoying.